# Is 0 necessary in 0777 here in PHP?

Tags: php, mkdir

```
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
```

Is the 0 in 0777 necessary?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. The leading zero will make the number interpreted as octal number; without it would be interpreted as decimal number.

```
var_dump(0700); // int(448)
var_dump(700);  // int(700)
```

Comment: But in bash environment I always use `chmod 777`,without 0,and it seems to be working.

Comment: Well technically it is not needed. It just makes it a hell of a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

The leading zero indicates an [octal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) value.
See also the documentation of [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's an [octal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) literal